# Jenkins Pipeline Kubernetes Agent shared Volumes

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

I have a Jenkins Pipeline using Kubernetes Agent.

I schedule multiple containers in my pod template.

I recently wanted to add volumes that would be shared some of the containers and am having difficulties.

I need to know how to create a volume that will be shared between 2 or more containers in a pod. That volume should mount to a specific path on each container.

**Specifics**:

- Using GCE (Google Cloud Engine) with Kubernetes Jenkins
- Using emptyDir volumes

There also seems to be a *severe lack of documentation* for this. So any direction on that would also be appreciated. The [documentation I did find](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#container-configuration) says that the way to do this is to define [volumes in the pipeline that will be shared by all containers.](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#pod-and-container-template-configuration)

**Sample Jenkinsfile**:

Below is not my actual pipeline, but it recreates the issue.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
    kubernetes {
      label 'test-pod'
      defaultContainer 'jnlp'
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: frontend-test
    image: centos:7
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
  - name: backend-test
    image: centos:7
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true   
  volumes:
  - name: sharedvolume
    emptyDir: {}
    mountPath: '/opt/app/shared'
"""
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test Pipeline Configuration') {
            steps {
                container('frontend-test') {
                    sh 'touch /opt/app/shared/test_file'
                }
                container('backend-test') {
                    sh 'ls /opt/app/shared/test_file ; echo $?'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**:

```
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
All nodes of label ‘test-pod’ are offline
Agent test-pod-5t0gj-wln8d is provisioned from template Kubernetes Pod Template
Agent specification [Kubernetes Pod Template] (test-pod): 

Running on test-pod-5t0gj-wln8d in /home/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test Pipeline Configuration)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[pipeline-test] Running shell script
+ touch /opt/app/shared/test_file
touch: cannot touch '/opt/app/shared/test_file': No such file or directory
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, you need to include the volume mounts in the containers [described here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/volumes#using_volumes):

**Sample Jenkinsfile**:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
    kubernetes {
      label 'test-pod'
      defaultContainer 'jnlp'
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: frontend-test
    image: centos:7
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: '/opt/app/shared'
      name: sharedvolume
  - name: backend-test
    image: centos:7
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true   
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: '/opt/app/shared'
      name: sharedvolume
  volumes:
  - name: sharedvolume
    emptyDir: {}
"""
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test Pipeline Configuration') {
            steps {
                container('frontend-test') {
                    sh 'touch /opt/app/shared/test_file'
                }
                container('backend-test') {
                    sh 'ls /opt/app/shared/test_file ; echo $?'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**:

This solved the problem.

```
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
All nodes of label ‘test-pod’ are offline
Agent test-pod-wv12q-brfxj is provisioned from template Kubernetes Pod Template
Agent specification [Kubernetes Pod Template] (test-pod): 

Running on test-pod-wv12q-brfxj in /home/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test Pipeline Configuration)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[pipeline-test] Running shell script
+ touch /opt/app/shared/test_file
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[pipeline-test] Running shell script
+ ls /opt/app/shared/test_file
/opt/app/shared/test_file
+ echo 0
0
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: quick question : may i know why u use "test-pod" ? did u configure it  in  /configure page? if so, please share with me your plugins conf